# Доступ к папке documents основного приложения из share-расширения

Tags: ios, swift4

Моё приложения представляет из себя что-то вроде текстового редактора. Его файлы хранятся в стандартной папке documents, путь к которой внутри приложения я получаю при помощи `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]`.

Собственно, как получить доступ к этой папке из share-расширения? Мне хотелось бы, что бы был интерфейс выбора директории, в которую пользователь хотел бы поместить тот или иной файл.

Заранее всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: если вы хотите что бы ваше приложение сохроняло файлы в document через UIActivity​View​Controller то можно прописать кастомный UIActivity (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity), а вот если из другого приложения сохранять в ваше то тут уже нужно делать share extension

Comment: @AndreyIskamov, никогда не работал с UIActivity... не могли бы вы привести пример?

Comment: вот пример с хабра https://habrahabr.ru/post/214637/ хоть там и шаринг в ВК но принцип похож, если я правильно понял что вы хотели

Comment: @AndreyIskamov, спасибо, посмотрю!